# Row re-order angular js in datatable

Tags: angularjs, datatables

I want to re-order row of data-table by drag and drop in `angular.js`.
Is there any way to do it?

I have tried `ui-sortable`, but it is not working with datatable.

Comment: Try to read the documentation at datatables.net and l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables...

Answer (score 0):

Use the following link:

[Datatable Row reorder](https://editor.datatables.net/examples/extensions/rowReorder)